# How to set the application domain in Heroku env var

Tags: heroku

Given an application URL on Heroru like `app-123.herokuapp.com`, how can I set this value into an environment variable?

I need to set an email template, with the correct links to the app, so there is no HTTP request information available, but I want to have the links with the correct URL.

I'm using Ruby on Rails and using an environment variable, but once I create review apps, with dynamic URL's I cannot rely on this.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This works only for the review apps, as they are my concern when posting the question.

We can make use of the injected environment variables, as described in the documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#injected-environment-variables

So, given that every application domain will be `herokuapp.com` we can guess the application address but concatenation of protocal, app and domain:

`"https://#{HEROKU_APP_NAME}.herokuapp.com"`